# How to add array with another array to create a multi-dimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have to recursively append around 40 arrays into a single array. I am creating an single array which will have all individual arrays because there is a hierarchy I want. I have attached image to showcase the hierarchy I want.
[Formatted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lPzW.png)

Below I am listing down a few example arrays and the example format of how I want them to be formatted in:

```
**array 1:**
array (
  'Shopping and fashion' => 
  array (
    'Beauty' => 
    array (
      'Cosmetics' => 
      array (
        'Cosmetics' => 
        array (
          0 => '6002839660079',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)

**array 2:**
array (
  'Business and industry' => 
  array (
    'Science' => 
    array (
      'Science' => 
      array (
        0 => '6002866718622',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)

**array 3:**
array (
  'Shopping and fashion' => 
  array (
    'Beauty' => 
    array (
      'Beauty' => 
      array (
        0 => '6002867432822',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

I want these arrays to be saved in a single array (if possible recursively).
Below is the format I want them to be saved in.

```
$myarray=
array (
  'Shopping and fashion' => 
  array (
    'Beauty' => 
    array (
      'Cosmetics' => 
      array (
        'Cosmetics' => 
        array (
          0 => 'Cosmetics-6002839660079',
        ),
      ),
      'Beauty' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Beauty-6002867432822',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  'Business and industry' => 
  array (
    'Science' => 
    array (
      'Science' => 
      array (
        0 => 'Science-6002866718622',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: `$myarray = [$array1, $array3, $array2];`

Comment: There are more than 40 arrays

Comment: Okay. What do the variables for the arrays look like? Are they sequentially named? How are these arrays generated in the first place?

Comment: The arrays are generated from my own function. The array is associative. Check the example array in the question. Array 1 and array 3 have the same keys so they become nested(as in attached image). Similarly a bunch of other arrays have similar keys and they're supposed to get nested into one another

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do `$myArray = array_merge($array1, $array2, $array3);`

Comment: Problem with merge is, it does not nest the arrays. The array[shopping and fashion] should have [cosmetics] and [beauty] inside it. Merge only keeps the latter